# Javascript Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have an ajax call and would like to recall it once I finish parsing and animating the result into the page. And that's where I'm getting stuck.

I was able to recall the function, but it seems to not take into account the delays in the animation. i.e. The console keeps outputting the values at a wild pace.

I thought setInterval might help with the interval being the sum of the length of my delays, but I can't get that to work...

```
function loadEm(){
    var result=new Array();     
    $.getJSON("jsonCall.php",function(results){
        $.each(results, function(i, res){
            rand = (Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*1000)+2000;
            fullRand += rand;
            console.log(fullRand);
            $("tr:first").delay(rand).queue(function(next) {
            doStuff(res);
                next();
            });
        });
        var int=self.setInterval("loadEm()",fullRand);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use `setTimeout`. `setInterval` will call again... and again... and again...
2. use `var fullRand` at the top of loadElm (or inside the JSON callback). Without it you will increment the *same global variable* each time loadElm is called. In fact, you should use `var` with *all* your local variables -- that includes `rand` here. [The Jibbering JavaScript Closure Notes](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) covers variables and much more.
3. use `setTimeout(loadElm, fullRand)` -- don't use a string in the first parameter :) See the [MDC setTimeout documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).
4. Check for JavaScript errors (keep firebug/IE developer tools/the error console handy)
5. Instead of using `setTimeout`, consider keeping count of how many of the animations have finished vs. how many total have finished! Imagine this:

===

```
// closure in JSON callback. see Jibbering notes.
var count = 0
$.each(results, function(i, res) {
  var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*1000)+2000
  count++ // have to do action
  $("tr:first").delay(rand).queue(function(next) {
    ...
    count-- // action done
    if (!count) { // means count == 0 here :-) then...
      loadElm() // ...all actions done
    }
  })
})
if (!count) {
  // err... no animations started :(
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement it and let you know!